# Append to mongodb from csv

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I have a mongodb with collection having fields email. fName, lName. And I have a csv with :

---

```
email | contactNo | countryName
a1    | 001       | USA        
a2    | 002       | UAE
```

---

I want to merge csv Data with mongoDB data with email as primary key.
The final mongo db should have fields like:

```
{
email:a1,
fName: tom,
lname: cruise,
contactNo: 001,
county : USA
}
```

Can I do this using mongoimport? Or how can I write a node/python script for same. Any link/refrence will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with v3.4, `mongoimport` supports the `--merge` flag. By default, it matches on `_id`, upserting any matches and inserting new id's. You can use the `--upsertFields` flag to specify an alternate field to match on (such as `email` in your case).

So, as an example: here is a simple collection, based on the data you have, which I created (I edited the formatting to make it fit better here):

```
db.contacts.find()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa019b79259d12040e7107b"),
    "fname" : "tom", "lname" : "cruise", "email" : "a1"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa019bb9259d12040e7107c"),
    "fname" : "bob", "lname" : "smith", "email" : "a2"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa019be9259d12040e7107d"),
    "fname" : "jane", "lname" : "jones", "email" : "a3"
}
```

And here is my csv file, for import:

```
email,contactNo,countryName
a1,1,USA
a2,2,UAE
a5,5,CAN
```

I now import with the following, specifying the `email` property as the property to key on (*not* `_id`):

```
mongoimport --mode merge --headerline --upsertFields email
 --db stackoverflow --collection contacts --file ~/import.csv --type csv
```

Once done, my data now looks like this:

```
db.contacts.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa019b79259d12040e7107b"),
    "fname" : "tom", "lname" : "cruise", "email" : "a1",
    "contactNo" : 1, "countryName" : "USA"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa019bb9259d12040e7107c"),
    "fname" : "bob", "lname" : "smith", "email" : "a2",
    "contactNo" : 2, "countryName" : "UAE"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa019be9259d12040e7107d"),
    "fname" : "jane", "lname" : "jones", "email" : "a3"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa019d17cd320319146756d"),
    "email" : "a5",
    "contactNo" : 5, "countryName" : "CAN"
}
```

Notice that:

- the first two documents have augmented to include data from the csv
- the third document is untouched, as there was no matching data in the csv
- the fourth document is brand-new, only containing properties from the csv

Also note that the `_id` property had nothing do do with the merge, because I specified the `--upsertFields` option when importing.

Read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#ex-mongoimport-merge) for more information.

Comment: But what if I don't have id in my csv. I have only contractNo and country?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you don't have `_id` you can choose any other property to merge on (with `--upsertFields` as I described above). And in MongoDB, an insert of an object without an `_id` will get you an auto-generated guid as an id.

Comment: The issue is mongo has id filed but csv doesn't. So it adds more documents. Now I have 1 record with id,fname,lname and second record with id,contractNo,country

Comment: I don't think you're understanding. You don't need `_id` and documents are only created when there's no match against the key field you designate (in this case, `email`). I edited my answer to show you an actual example demonstrating this.

Comment: I was missing something in csv.Thanks now the answer is more helpful :)

Comment: if  `_id` field is there in my csv file, do I still need to specify `--upsertFields id` option?